# Hide output of ssh command

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to hide the output of this command:

`string=$(su - user -c "ssh $L_NAME 'cat ~/.ssh/known_hosts'")`

I've tried to do:

`string=$(su - user -c "ssh $L_NAME 'cat ~/.ssh/known_hosts'") &> /dev/null`

but it doesn't work. Does anyone know how to hide the output of the ssh command in this case?

Thanks

Comment: the assignment itself doesn't have output.  It's coming from the subcommand, what do you expect the value of string when you null the output?

Comment: yes, i would expect it to be null. however, when i run the script it shows the ssh output

Comment: move the redirect into the parenthesis then.

Comment: What is the output you want to get rid of? What causes it? Does the remote host print a host banner or some such? Does `.hushlogin` help?

Comment: If i do that it will clear the string value..

Comment: yes the remote host prints a host banner which i want to hide

Comment: didn't you just said "yes, i would expect it to be null"

Comment: You're right, i've made a mistake there. I want the string to keep its value, however I do not want command to print the remote host banner

Comment: have you tried: string=$(su - user -c "ssh $L_NAME 'cat ~/.ssh/known_hosts'" 2>&-)

Comment: THATS IT! Thanks you so much!

Comment: I'll give you something as an answer to pick then-- that way it's "resolved"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try turning off STDERR in the command.

```
string=$(su - user -c "ssh $L_NAME 'cat ~/.ssh/known_hosts'" 2>&-)
```